# Using multiple aggregate functions in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is as below

```
WORKS ( emp-name, comp-name, salary)
```

I want to find the comp-name which pays to lowest total salary to it's employees

I tries below query, but it gives SUM of salaries for all comp-name

```
SELECT  comp-name, MIN(sal) as lowest
FROM
(
    SELECT comp-name, SUM(salary) as sal from WORKS group by comp-name
)tmt group by comp-name;
```

How do I find only one company which pays lowest total salary.

Comment: Wait, no primary key ? I'll assume that e's are unique. If true, then should'nt it be `select c,min(s) from words group by c`

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIMIT to get only one company with lowest total salary , also need to need to sort in ascending order

```
     SELECT comp-name, 
     SUM(salary) as sal 
     from WORKS 
     group by comp-name
     Order by sal ASC
     LIMIT 1
```